Why do enantiomers come in pairs (there never is a third enantiomer)?
In this problem, they are showing three structures that are all enantiomers of the original structure:

Of the three ways to draw an enantiomer, only the first method involves interchanging wedges and dashes. Even so, make sure to understand that all three of these methods produce the same answer:

All three drawings represent the same compound. They might look different, but rotation of any one drawing will generate the other drawings. Remember that a molecule can only have one enantiomer, so all three methods must produce the same answer. In general, it is easiest to use the first method. Simply redraw the compound, replacing all dashes with wedges and all wedges with dashes. However, this method will not work in all situations. In some molecular drawings, wedges and dashes are not drawn, because the three-dimensional geometry is implied by the drawing.

By three methods mentioned here they meant "placing the mirror behind, beside and beneath the molecule".
In the text, it says "Remember that a molecule can only have one enantiomer, so all three methods must produce the same answer." Why is it that a molecule can have only one enantiomer?

This question is very ambiguous. the example molecule could have two enantiomers but only one is shown (all three pictures show the same enantiomer as the question says). The sentence "a molecule can have only one enantiomer" would better be written as "the way you draw the structure of a molecule does not change which enantiomer the drawing represents". "Molecule" is ambiguous as it could mean a specific enantiomer or  all the molecules with the same connectivity.

@matt_black I tried to make the question less ambiguous through my edits, hopefully preserving the intent of the OP.

This is a mathematical answer. To make the connection to chemistry, we have to agree that:

We call two structures identical if we can superimpose them using translations and rotations (the rotations are of the entire structure, not parts of it).

Whether we call two molecules identical is a bit more complicated (allowing for conformational change), but we don't need this concept here.


So I want to show that there is a single structure produced when you apply a mirror operation on a three-dimensional shape (like a molecular structure). I am using the following properties of mirror operations:
a) The inverse of a mirror operation is the mirror operation itself (applying the same mirror plane twice gets you back to the original object, unrotated and untranslated).
b) Applying two mirror operations with two mirror planes at different orientations results in a pure rotation, and with two mirror planes that are parallel results in a pure translation.
When you apply different mirror operations to an object A, you get different results, for example A' and A''. You can show that A' and A'' are related just by translation and rotation. To do that, start with A', apply the mirror operation that turned A into A', giving you A again (property a). Then, apply the mirror operation that turned A into A'', giving you A''. Apparently, a combination of two mirror operations turns A' into A'', showing that they are related by a pure rotation or translation (property b). This means two molecular structures that are both the enantiomer of a given molecular structure are identical, so there is only one possible enantiomer.
Property a) and property b) are fun to prove (with some choice of coordinate systems and using polar coordinates), but that probably is off-topic here.

To get the enantiomer of a molecule, you change the configuration of all of its stereocenters (R to S or S to R). There's only one way to do that. For example, if I have (2R, 3R)-3-chlorobutan-2-ol, its ONLY enantiomer must be (2S, 3S)-3-chlorobutan-2-ol. Note that, if I have (2R, 3S)-3-chlorobutan-2-ol, its enantiomer is (2S, 3R)-3-chlorobutan-2-ol. So 3-chlorobutan-2-ol has two "pairs" of enantiomers: (2R,3R)/(2S,3S) is one pair, and (2R,3S)/(2S,3R) is another pair. But any specific stereoisomer of 3-chlorobutan-2-ol only has one enantiomer.
No matter where a mirror plane is located, passing a molecule through that mirror plane always inverts all of its stereocenters. You can imagine that, whether you're looking at yourself in a mirror in front of you or standing on a mirror, the image in the mirror is your one and only "mirror image." For example, if you raise your right hand, your image in the mirror would look like its left hand was raised; it doesn't matter if the mirror is left of you, right of you, on top of you, behind you, etc.

Enantiomers are mirror images of each other so you can't have three enantiomers
Eg you and your mirror image are different and you can't have more than one mirror image of yourself
